# Extract Json response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to to extract a Json response in jquery sent from a php file.
This is the .js code:

```
    $.ajax({
 url: 'index.php?page=register', //This is the current doc
 type: 'POST',
 datatype: 'json',
 data: {'userCheck': username},
 success: function(data){
    // Check if username is available or not
 },
 error: function(){
    alert('Much wrong, such sad');
 }
});
```

This is the response from the php file:

```
    if($sth->fetchColumn()!=0){
        //$response = array("taken");
        $response = array("username"=>"taken");
        echo json_encode($response);
        //echo '{"username':'taken"}';
    }else{
        //$response = array("available");
        $response = array("username"=>"available");
        echo json_encode($response);
        //echo '{"username":"available"}';
    }
```

I have tried all combinations I can think of in both files, but nothing seems to work. It is a simple check for a username in the database. If I console log the data I get from the response, I get this:

```
    {"username":"available"}<!DOCTYPE html>
    // The rest of the page html
```

So the info is there, but how do I access it? I have tried several syntaxes found around the internet, but no luck so far. I seem to recall that a json response only can contain valid json, so is the problem the html? I don't think I can avoid this due to the structure of my application, so hopefully it is possible to access the json with my present structure.

Comment: Are you sending **header("Content-Type: application/json");** before the **echo**?

Comment: @user2182349 Why does that matter? He has `dataType: "json"` in the AJAX call, so it will ignore the content type.

Comment: @MaDaHoPe: answered ;) dont forget to exit(); to avoid including html page in json response !

Comment: @Barmar - It is good practice to set the **Content-Type** to reflect the content served.

Comment: @user2182349 Perhaps, but it's won't make a difference if you code it explicitly on the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**in you Ajax**

**EDIT:**

change

```
datatype:"json",
```

the case of parameter name was not respected, the t must be T

```
dataType:"json",
```

now retry please

```
$.ajax
({
    url: 'index.php?page=register', //This is the current doc
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {'userCheck': username},
    success: function(data)
    {
        // Check if username is available or not
        switch(data.username)
        {
            case "available":
                // do you want
                break;
            case "taken":
                // do you want
                break;
        }
    },
    error: function()
    {
        alert('Much wrong, such sad');
    }
});
```

**in PHP**

simply that, and don't forget to exit; to avoid include html page in your json response !
This is the code coming after the }".... who break your json output
and make it unreadable by javascript (worste, it simply break your javascript !)

```
echo json_encode(["username"=> ($sth->fetchColumn()!=0) ? "taken":"available"]);
exit;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Completely missed exit; I now get the correct json, but the switch statement doesn't do anything. Just testing it with a simple alert, but nothing is happening :-/ Any idea as to why?

Comment: console.log(data) really show {"username":"available"} not appear to be a string but an accesible object, and don't work with some answered code (like mine and barmar) ? can you taking a screenshoot ?

Comment: I will try that. I managed to solve it with a JSON.parse of the data, but your solution looks quite more elegant. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: and more optimized, it has been designed for
i think you can valid my answer for future beginners visiting this page  ;)
and please update you code to explain the JSON.parse() method. ah your welcome

Comment: Actually this didn't work for me. I still need to parse the response into a JSON object for the JS to recognise it. I parse the data received like this: var newUser = JSON.parse(data); and then I can access the newUser variable with syntax for the data variable. I am not quite sure why I need to do this, but remembering to exit; to avoid the rest of the document was vital for getting there. I will update my working code as soon as I am on my own computer and have access to my localhost.

Comment: It did work! Sorry for my earlier comment. I was tired and forgot to save the file before checking, remember sleep my friends. And paying attention to detail, totally missed the capital T when reviewing my older projects where this actually worked. This is the working solution all the way through!

Answer (score 2):

When you're responding to an AJAX call, you should just return the JSON response, not the HTML of the page. Add:

```
exit();
```

after this code so you don't display the HTML after the JSON.

In the JS code, use `if (data.username == 'available')` to tell whether the username is available.

The other problem in your code is that you have a typo here:

```
datatype: 'json',
```

It should be `dataType`, with an uppercase `T`.

You can also put:

```
header("Content-type: application/json");
```

before echoing the JSON in the script, and jQuery will automatically parse the response.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The exit solved the first part of my problem. However, the if (data.username == 'available') does nothing?? Just testing with a simple alert, but nothing... Same with @MTroy s switch statement, nothing happens. I have looked at old projects ( REALLY old ) and there this exact syntax is working, so I am rather puzzled as to why it is not working in this case...

Comment: {"username":"available"}. So the json is valid.

Comment: I can't see any reason why my answer wouldn't work. You're only checking the response in the `success` function, not elsewhere in your code, right?

Comment: I found the problem. I needed to parse the response into an object. So now it's working, yaaay! Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: NO, you don't need to parse anything since you use dataType:"json", but you just invalidate the case of this parameter by forget to type "t" instead of "T"

Comment: @MaDaHoPe `dataType: "json"` tells jQuery to parse it automatically, you shouldn't need to parse it yourself. You just had a typo, as MTroy pointed out.

Comment: Thanks guys, very grateful!! I accepted MTroy's answer as he has a nifty php snippet as well, but thank you for all your help as well @Barmar

Answer (score 0):

Also you can set request headers in your jQuery ajax call beforeSend function like follows

```
beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=utf-8');
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
}
```

So you're strictly declaring the data type to be json